# C# interactive window displays `Submission#30+E` as type of an enum

Tags: c#, c#-interactive

What does the statement `Submission#30+E` mean if I try to output the type of the enumeration in the console using C# interactive window in Visual Studio:

```
> enum E { First, Second};
> Console.WriteLine(typeof(E));
Submission#30+E
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getunderlyingtype(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a characteristic of the C# interactive window. Due to the way the interactive window works, offering a [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) for a language that is actually compiled, the interactive window will compile every line you send to it separately. So internally, each of those “submissions” is handled and compiled individually.

The submissions are then indexed starting from 0. So the first submission is compiled into the `Submission#0`, the second into `Submission#1` and so on. In your case, `Submission#30` means it was the 31st input you sent to the C# interactive window during that Visual Studio session.

What actually happens internally is that the code you submit is compiled into its own type. So every submission results in its own type to be used to evaluate the interactive input. You guessed right, `Submission#n` is exactly that type.

The remainder of what you see is `+E`. When looking at type names, a plus in the name means that it is a nested type. Consider the following example:

```
public class Foo
{
    public class Bar
    { }
}
```

Here, `Bar` is nested inside `Foo`. If you look at `typeof(Foo.Bar).ToString()` (which is called when you evaluate `typeof(Foo.Bar)` in the interactive prompt), you get back `Foo+Bar`. So you have `Bar` nested inside of `Foo`.

So coming back to your situation, you have all the pieces you need to understand what’s going on: `Submission#30+E` means it’s the 31st submission to the interactive window, and there is a nested type `E` inside of the automatically created type `Submission#30`.

And if you think about it, it makes totally sense: Since everything you submit to the prompt is compiled into its own type, type definitions will have to be nested inside of that automatically created type. And that’s exactly what happened with `E`.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation!.